# ¿Existe alguna expresión regular que me permita seleccionar las coincidencias con estas condiciones?

Tags: regex, shell-script

He estado tratando de ver alguna forma de conseguir lo siguiente:

A partir del input:

lorem d5, ipsum, asd ffs: 5455, 45454, 232334, 23234.

Seleccionar mediante 1 sola expresión regular todas las comas (solo las comas) que estén antecedidas por un número del texto que siga después del texto "asd ff":

He probado de varias formas con la lookbehind pero sólo consigo cumplir una de las dos condiciones a la vez, habrá alguna otra forma de conseguirlo?

Comment: ¿Y tiene que ser con una expresión regular?

Comment: @Mauricio Así es, debe ser una expresión regular

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible con una expresión regular, ya que necesitas usar grupos que se repiten y estos solo hacen match a la última iteración, por lo que primero tendrías que obtener la parte de texto después de "asd ff" y a ese string aplicarle la expresión que haga match a una coma.

Para seleccionar cada coma que sigue después de "asd ff" con una sola expresión, tendrías que repetir el patrón N veces dentro de la expresión regular pero esto no es nada práctico